# Insert Image using Jade and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, html-table, pug

How can I use an object that I've passed through to jade within an image, I'm also using mongodb to hold the data.

Currently this is my code:

```
db.collection('blogposts', function(err, collection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('table', { title: 'Blog Posts', tab: "list" , blogposts: docs });
    });
});
```

So I have the nodejs passing through a mongodb collection through to jade,
Then within Jade I have:

```
div.span9
    table.table.table-bordered.table-striped.noborder

        each row in blogposts
            tr
                td
                    div.blogtitle #{row.Title}
                    br
                    div.blogheading #{row.Heading}
                    br
                    div.namedate #{row.Namedate}
                    br
                    div.imagetable
                        img(src='')
                    br
                    div.blogposts #{row.Posts}
                    br
                    div.blogtags Tags: #{row.Tags}
```

And what I'm trying to do is use `#{row.Image}` within the actual `img(src='')` as the source.

It appears that I must use some other syntax or something to use it within the source as just putting it in doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do `img(src= "http://" + row.Image)`

Jade will treat the `src` attribute value as a javascript expression, evaluate it and render the HTML as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks, it is now taking in the variable, however the image source is based from a link(ie http://www.something.com/picture.jpg). The problem here is that even though the variable im pushing through has " around it(that is its showing up as "http://www.something.com/picture.jpg"), it doesnt recognise that it is an outside link and wants to get the image from localhost. I was wondering how to make it recognise that its pulling the image from a website?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, it already has http://, the full thing im sending through to Jade is "http://www.something.com/picutre.jpg"

Comment: After fiddling around with the quotation marks it appears to now work, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My url already had https:// prepended. The solution that worked was:

```
img(src=row.Image)
```

Answer (score 0):

While if you are sending a link it might work the way has been detailed. If you are sending over the data as a base64 encoded string, then you must prepend the following to your picture data:

"data:image/png;base64,"

So you would have: img(src= "data:image/png;base64," + row.ImageDataBase64)